# Android Designed for Phones

Tags: android, android-manifest, uses-feature

So I encountered a problem with my app on the google play store. My app is designed for both phone and tablet but it appears that it is only designed for phones according to the google play store. I thought I had fixed it by setting `telephony` to `false` but that didn't work. Before I submit an alpha version 1.0.1, I wanted to make sure these parameters are right... I just started Android 1 month ago so I am unfamiliar with the process. Any help would be great!

I have these permissions:

```
<!--
    Internet Services
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!--
     Location Services
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!--
    Parse Services
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.newsensor.electro_harmonix.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.newsensor.electro_harmonix.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!--
    Phone Services
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I am going to implement these features:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
              android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"
              android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
              android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
              android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
```

I have also included these supports:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

EDIT: So I uploaded it and tested it as a beta version just now. It downloaded on my tablet but when I view the app in "my apps" in the google play store, it still says "Designed for phones". Is this because I have to push the app into production?

Comment: have you uploaded tablet screenshots?

Comment: The information you posted does not matter. Designed does not mean 'configured', designed means that it looks well on either tabled or phone

Comment: @Gaskoin so this is an issue of configuration?

Comment: @Gaskoin so you haven't read the question?

Comment: You can also send a question for google https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq

Comment: The information from @Gaskoin is correct. Go to https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html to ensure you are doing things Google expects for tablet optimised apps. If you feel you are already doing everything appropriate for your app, you can use the form linked by Gaskoin. There is some form of automated check that your app has been designed to give a good tablet experience(not just that it will run on a tablet). A couple of my apps showed 'Designed for Phones', I used the contact form, explained the tablet operation of the app and they updated the listing

Comment: @LewisMcGeary thanks Lewis! I'll try that out once I make sure I'm doing everything Google expects me to.

Comment: @Gaskoin ah I see what you mean now, sorry for the slowness. ugh I feel dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that permissions are good. But can you check what sdkversion you set for minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. If it is less then or equal to '10'. Then i guess that will be creating a problem for not supporting the Tablets. Earlier there was no support for large-screens.

Comment: My min SDK is 15. So I uploaded it and tested it as a beta version just now. It downloaded on my tablet but when I view the app in "my apps" in the google play store, it still says "Designed for phones". Is this because I have to push the app into production?